# How to remove all items from many-to-many collection in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, many-to-many, sqlalchemy

when I need to remove an object from declarative ORM many-to-many relationship, I am supposed to do this:

```
blogpost.tags.remove(tag)
```

Well. What am I supposed to do if I need to purge all these relations (not only one)? Typical situation: I'd like to set a new list of tags to my blogpost. So I need to...:

1. **Remove all existing relations** between that blogpost and tags.
2. Set new relations and create new tags if they don't exist.

Of course, there could be a better way of doing this. In that case please let me know.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the standard Python idiom for clearing a list – assigning to the “entire list” slice:

```
blogpost.tags[:] = []
```

Instead of the empty list, you may want assign the new set of tags directly.

```
blogpost.tags[:] = new_tags
```

---

SQLAlchemy's relations are [instrumented attributes](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/collections.html#custom-collection-implementations), meaning that they keep the interface of a list (or set, dict, etc), but any changes are reflected in the database. This means that anything you can do with a list is possible with a relation, while SQLA transparently listens to the changes and updates the database accordingly.

Comment: Or put it otherwise: SQLAlchemy is awesome.

Comment: Why not just `blogpost.tags = new_tags`? (without [:])

Comment: When I try this now (Dec 2014, SQLAlchemy 0.9) I get "TypeError: 'AppenderBaseQuery' object does not support item assignment."

Comment: I spent a long time searching google for "SQLAlchemy how to replace all relationship elements". Commenting that here to hopefully help ease of search.

@Devi this doesn't work. You'd be replacing an sqla Collection object with a new type (list)

Comment: Many things must have changed as the library have evolved over versions/years and the accepted and once working answers may not work now. It's better to be precise with the versions in both Q and A.

Answer (score 14):

Confrimed for what [Two-Bit Alchemist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588818/two-bit-alchemist) has reported.

```
blogpost.tags[:] = new_tags
```

will complain about

```
TypeError: 'AppenderBaseQuery' object does not support item assignment
```

But

```
blogpost.tags = new_tags
```

seems to work fine.

Comment: This doesn't persist anything to database, meaning setting to empty list doesn't clear records

Comment: @kevlarr this does work because the `tags` field of the `blogpost` object is also instrumented; when you assign an empty list to it, the empty list is replaced with an empty `sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery` object.

Comment: @Tom I'd be curious then if it was a version issue, because I had tried exactly that with different results from what you're reporting. I don't have access to the code anymore, though, so not sure what version I was using (it would have been latest at the time of my comment). Are you sure that the assignment of the empty list *actually removes database records*?